# how to get imported library version on Application

Tags: android, android-library

I was using a custom library imported on my Application (Im not the one who make the library)and now, i want to know what is the version of this custom library created. Is there something i can inspect the version of this custom library?.

by the way, this is the name of my library i was using:
[image]

as you see, the implemented library does not have library-version.

And this is the file i was using for:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. connect to internet
2. from android studio open **project structure** (its icon is a gray rectangle with three blue squares on it)
3. If you want to see versions go to **dependencies** tab but if you want to update libraries go to (4)
4. in **project structure** go to **suggestions** wait for it to loads
5. if there is any update it notifies you to update with an update button for every library that needs update

Comment: yes sir, this is might be the answer but for my problem, i was figure it out the answer and the answer for his question is depends on the library developed.. since i was using custom library. i just look around for these too but unfortunately, the developed haven't  put the versioning of its work. but in some cases, you explain well the answer. thnak you.

Answer (score 0):

the answer for this is no versioning. since it was created as a custom library, but the developer not added its vesioning so that i cant figure it out the version.. tho the answer ofthe first comment is specifically right answer for the pre- library installed.